# How do I do "Hello World" to try using cron

Tags: cron

I am using Fedora 20, and want, eventually, to set up automatic backups. I managed a trial run on my previous Fedora 12 installation, but can't get started again. I am using zshell.

I thought I would get going by scheduling a shell program to show a zenity window with a "Hello World" message every minute. The zenity call is:

`zenity --info --text='Something very nice has happened!' --title="Zenity"`

which I put in a file `/testrsync/zenitytest.sh`, which works nicely when I call it from a command line.

I have edited `crontab` to contain: `* * * * * /testrsync/zenitytest.sh`

And nothing happens. I am obviously overlooking something, but I cannot yet see what.  (I have tried all sorts of things, too numerous to describe here.) Please can anyone help?

---

After further research I tried the following,

```
[Harry@localhost]~/testrsync%  /sbin/service crond status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l crond.service
crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2014-09-22 10:37:42 BST; 3h 24min ago
 Main PID: 709 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─709 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Sep 22 13:58:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 13:58:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 13:59:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 13:59:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 14:00:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 14:00:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 14:01:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 14:01:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 14:02:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Sep 22 14:02:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
[Harry@localhost]~/testrsync%
```

I then amended my crontab to read:

`* * * * * /testrsync/zenitytest.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

But the only effect was to stop the error messages , same as above, with different timings, and the last line:

`Sep 22 14:04:01 localhost.localdomain crond[709]: (Harry) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/Harry)`

Comment: This will not work since cron can only write output to STDOUT. It has no access to your X server nor should it. So the approach you're taking is incorrect. Rather you should be writing to a file under say `/tmp` a timestamp or something, and then monitoring that file. If a GUI is required then you'd make that a separate tool that would monitor this output file from the crontab entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application started via `cron` has no connected terminal or even X available.

So there is nothing where your window can be displayed.

To test such things use a file and append anything to this. Then you can look in the file (e.g. with `tail -f`) and see that the `cron` is running.

Comment: Thank you Uwe, and sim, that worked perfectly. I don't think I would have found that explanation elsewhere, since I would not have known what to look for, without a lot of serious delving.